# Applescript: forward Outlook email as attachment

Tags: applescript, email, ms-office, attachments

I have an AppleScript service that helps me automate reporting spam/phishing email to our IT group.  I noticed that it forwards by embedding the content directly in the forwarded message, which triggers loading its images by URL, which is undesirable for spam because it can reveal to the sender that I opened the message.  (This happens despite having "Automatically download pictures from the Internet" in *Preferences -> Email -> Reading* set to "Never".)

Right now I do the forwarding like this:

```
tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
    -- See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42982738/applescript-for-outlook-v15-recipients-wont-populate

    set fwdMessage to forward theMessage without opening window
    make new recipient at fwdMessage ¬
        with properties {email address:{address:"spam@example1.com"}}
    make new recipient at fwdMessage ¬
        with properties {email address:{address:"spam@example2.com"}}
    open fwdMessage

    move theMessage to junk mail
end tell
```

How can I modify that to do a "Forward As Attachment" instead of a regular "Forward" action?

I'm using Outlook version 16.16.16.

Comment: Could you make it work like saving the mail to some folder on desktop etc, and then picking the attachment later in the script. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/339274/apple-script-fail-on-copying-attachment-from-outlook?rq=1